# erlang,net_adm:ping() return pang but i can see the node in nodes().why？

Tags: erlang, cluster-computing

I have this code：
[erlang code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJG6d.png)

run it：

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3Mim.png)

other nodes is :
[other node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVYgf.png)

why Zzh1 is pang?

Ps. sorry I can not post pic...

Answer (score 1):

As We can see, even though cookie in both the nodes seems to be same, nodes() is returning [].

Can you please give a try with following commands.

```
erlang:set_cookie('test@vmailpush',<< the same cookie>>).
net_adm:ping('test@vmailpush').
```

Please run this command from the node where you are trying to ping i.e newmc@vmailpush

Comment: Thanks！I have resolved this problem，The host's hostname have some mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

In your printout, nodes() returned an empty list - the nodes are not connected. net_adm:names() queries the local epmd daemon, which shows that the test node is registered there, but it says nothing about connectedness. It could simply be that your nodes have different cookies and refuse to connect.

Comment: Thank you very much .but I sure that cookie is same ....I just post a pic in text